# how to create a dynamodb table in python boto

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am following the below document to create table [boto dynamodb documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/dynamodb_tut.html)

```
message_table_schema = conn.create_schema(
        hash_key_name='forum_name',
        hash_key_proto_value=str,
        range_key_name='subject',
        range_key_proto_value=str
    )

table = conn.create_table(
        name='messages',
        schema=message_table_schema,
        read_units=10,
        write_units=10
    )
```

I am trying the following code but some how the dynamodb object is not able to find the create_schema table.

`AttributeError: 'DynamoDBConnection' object has no attribute 'create_schema'`

Please let me know if this method is deprecated or if there any other way to create a table.

Comment: How did you create the `conn`?

Comment: conn=boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(args.region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DynamoDBConnection` created using `boto.dynamodb2` does not have `create_schema` method. It is part of **`boto.dynamodb.layer2.Layer2`** API.

Create the connection using,

```
import boto.dynamodb
conn = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(region)
```

Or to create a table with `boto.dynamodb2`, use this **[`create_table`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.layer1.DynamoDBConnection.create_table)** method or **[`Table`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.Table)** instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link you mentioned for dynamodb2, I can see the syntax for it but can not see any example for it. so you have any example or any link of the same?

Comment: If you need an example of how to pass the `key_schema`, refer how `schema` is passed to `create` example [here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html#boto.dynamodb2.table.Table).